# Bootstrap 4-Col 2-Row div responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, multiple-columns

How can i make a 4 x 2 Column Div in bootstrap responsive on mobile devices?
Preferably so they all collapse below one another at a certain breakpoint.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="services-col-1">
    <div class="col-xs-3" id="p1"><strong>Heading One</strong><p>Mauris tristique pharetra luctus. Curabitur fermentum orci at sapien sollicitudin, maximus viverra sem tincidunt. sem tincidunt.Mauris tristique pharetra luctus. Curabitur fermentum orci at sapien sollicitudin, maximus viverra sem tincidunt. sem tincidunt.</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-half-offset" id="p2"><strong>Heading Two</strong><p>Mauris tristique pharetra luctus. Curabitur fermentum orci at sapien sollicitudin, maximus viverra sem tincidunt. sem tincidunt.Mauris tristique pharetra luctus. Curabitur fermentum orci at sapien sollicitudin, maximus viverra sem tincidunt. sem tincidunt.</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-half-offset" id="p3"><strong>Heading Three</strong><p>Mauris tristique pharetra luctus. Curabitur fermentum orci at sapien sollicitudin, maximus viverra sem tincidunt. sem tincidunt.Mauris tristique pharetra luctus. Curabitur fermentum orci at sapien sollicitudin, maximus viverra sem tincidunt. sem tincidunt.</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-half-offset" id="p4"><strong>Heading Four</strong><p>Mauris tristique pharetra luctus. Curabitur fermentum orci at sapien sollicitudin, maximus viverra sem tincidunt. sem tincidunt.Mauris tristique pharetra luctus. Curabitur fermentum orci at sapien sollicitudin, maximus viverra sem tincidunt. sem tincidunt.</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-half-offset" id="p5"><strong>Heading Five</strong><p>Mauris tristique pharetra luctus. Curabitur fermentum orci at sapien sollicitudin, maximus viverra sem tincidunt. sem tincidunt.Mauris tristique pharetra luctus. Curabitur fermentum orci at sapien sollicitudin, maximus viverra sem tincidunt. sem tincidunt.</p></div>    
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-half-offset" id="p6"><strong>Heading Six</strong><p>Mauris tristique pharetra luctus. Curabitur fermentum orci at sapien sollicitudin, maximus viverra sem tincidunt. sem tincidunt.Mauris tristique pharetra luctus. Curabitur fermentum orci at sapien sollicitudin, maximus viverra sem tincidunt. sem tincidunt.</p></div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you make sniper and make more specifie.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question clearly ?

Comment: My mistake i meant 4 columns 2 rows. It displays as it should on desktop but when the width reduces they get narrower. I need them to collapse below one another on smaller screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need two rows with 4 columns, if yes. There is a solution with Bootstrap as you mentioned.

In one row there must be max 12 col in total. `12 total / 4 columns = 3 (col-*-3)`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
      One of four columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
      One of four columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
      One of four columns
    </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
      One of four columns
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
      One of four columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
      One of four columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
      One of four columns
    </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
      One of four columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make each div collapse below one another after the screen size reduces to mobile? as i'm going to have at least a paragraph of text in each div.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do it is to use `.col-xs-12` class for targetting mobile devices.

Checkout this **[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GNJKVL)**

Or look at the snippet below:

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
      One of four columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
      One of four columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
      One of four columns
    </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
      One of four columns
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
      One of four columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
      One of four columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
      One of four columns
    </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
      One of four columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!